# How to create multiple barcharts in a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Few rows of my data are like:

[image]

I am trying to write a loop program in R that takes a set of rows with similar names/values and produces the bar plots in a loop for rows with similar names/values stored in a single column "Variable_name" in R.

so far, I have tried to create a separate data table for each set of rows, filtering by row values and then passing it to ggplot.

**[*Works but don't want to go through this process*] Tedious/Manual process:**

```
data[is.na(data)]<-'NA' #Turning NA as a valid value so that it get's included in the bar diagram.

bar_data1 <- data %>%
filter(Variable_name == 'Gender')

ggplot(bar_data1, aes(x=Levels, y=Count, fill=Levels))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme_minimal()+scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,20,50,100,150))
```

**[*Want but doesn't work*] I also tried this for loop:**

```
for(i in 1:2){
print(ggplot(data, aes(x=Levels, y=Count, fill=Levels))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme_minimal()+scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,20,50,100,150)))
}
```

The issue with the loop program that I have written is that it runs forever and ultimately R stops responding. Is it running out of memory? I think there is something wrong with my loop program.

Any advice on how to make it work through the loop program?

Comment: Are you looking for independent graphs, and then, could you use face_wrap?:
ggplot(data, aes(x=Levels, y=Count, fill=Levels))+geom_bar(stat="identity") + face_wrap(~Variable_name)

Comment: `print()` should not work with `ggplot()`, you are probably looking for another command (e.g. `ggsave()` or nothing at all to just display it).

Also the loop should just print the same command twice, as there is nothing that changes in function of `i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example with mtcars. We gonna plot 3 histograms with 3 groups based on the number of `cyl` of the cars:

Instead of a for loop we gonna use the `purrr::map()` function :

```
library(tidyverse)

groups <- names(table(mtcars$cyl))

plots <- map(groups,
     function(group) {
       (
         mtcars
         %>% filter(cyl == group)
         %>% ggplot(aes(hp))
          +  geom_histogram()
       )})

print(plots)
```

---

But if you want to plot all histograms on the same figure, use `facet_wrap()`:

```
(
    mtcars
    %>% ggplot(aes(hp))
     +  geom_histogram()
     +  facet_wrap(~cyl)
)
```

Comment: Thank you Pietrodito, your example works but when I tried to adapt it for my data. I got an error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" written multiple times. Any advice on resolving that error.

Comment: Please edit your queston with the exact data and code. And if you like my answer accept it.

Comment: Tks for accepting the answer, if you want more info on the warning "longer object length..." this is hard without a reproductible example (search what it is). But I guess the problem is with the `==` in filter. How did you compute the `groups` exactly?

Comment: No worries, I resolved it. It was due to not specifying anything in the parenthesis after aes. Silly mistake. Thanks for the edit and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly and you want to use a for loop, you are looking at something like this (the example is untested):

```
for(value in names(table(data$Variable_name))){

     assign(paste0("data_", value), filter(data, Variable_name == value))

     ggplot(paste0("data_", value), aes(x=Levels, y=Count, fill=Levels))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      theme_minimal()+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,20,50,100,150))
}
```

Comment: Thank you Giulio, When I tried to adapt your code. I got an error "'data' must be a data frame, or other object coercible by 'fortify()', not a character vector". I did change my data table into data frame using following data1 <- setDF(data)  . Any advice on resolving this error?

Comment: Would you be able to post what kind of object `data` is?

Comment: Sure, the data is an data.table object.